# Numerical differentiation using forward difference method

Tags: matlab, computational-mathematics

I am trying to calculate the fourth derivative of order $O(h^2)$ and $O(h^4)$ of any function $f$, through the forward finite difference method, and which coefficients are given in this Wikipedia's article

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference_coefficient

I wrote this code considering such article
[image]

However, in non of both i get the result should be.

Comment: I used $f(x)=\sin(x)$ at $t=\pi/3$ with $h=0.0001$, however i get $-37.7476$ for $O(h^2)$ and $-479.6163$ for $O(h^4)$

Comment: something curious that happened is that when $h$ is not of the form $10^{(-n)}$ the program works perfectly